# Javascript and Java Servlets: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, tomcat, websocket

Trying to update some information in an html/jsp file trough WebSockets using Java Servlets and tomcat 8.5 to connect to a RMI server. The error is:

```
VM281:164 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/sd/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

This is our Javascript connection code:

```
var websocket;
var elId = null;
window.onload = function() {
    connect("ws://"+document.location.host+"/sd/ws")
}
function connect(host) { // connect to the host websocket
if ('WebSocket' in window)
    websocket = new WebSocket(host);
else if ('MozWebSocket' in window)
    websocket = new MozWebSocket(host);
return;
websocket.onopen    = onOpen; // set the event listeners below
websocket.onclose   = onClose;
websocket.onmessage = onMessage;
websocket.onerror   = onError;
}
```

And our Java Servlet code is like this:

```
package ws;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import rmi.Election;
import rmi.ServerInterface;

import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.Session;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws")
public class ElectionInfoWebSocket {
    private Session session;
    private boolean isUp;
    private ServerInterface rmiCon;
    private String naming =  "//127.0.0.1:7000/server";
    private String elId = "";

    public ElectionInfoWebSocket() {

    }

    @OnOpen
    public void start(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
        isUp = true;
        sendMessage("meme");
    }
}
```

I have imported the java.websocket jar into the lib file and it does not work still. Having tried all of the solutions in here nothing works, and the URI seems to be right since we have tested every possibilty.